# Method not getting Unit test code coverage for change event

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am running a a Jasmine test on my Angular application. I have created a test that passes and I assumed it would cover my change event method. The input is a set of radio buttons. and all I am testing is that the value changed when the event was triggered.

**.ts file**

```
  onBehalfOfChangeEvent(x) {
        const value = x.value; // this line not covered on report
        this.params.onBehalfOf = value; // this line not covered on report
    }
```

**.html file**

```
       <div formGroupName="onBehalfOfGroup" class="form-group">
        <div *ngFor="let radio of onBehalfOfArray; let i = index">
        <label class="col-12 customradio"
          ><span>{{ radio.value }}</span>
          <input
            [ngClass]="{ checked: registerForm.get('onBehalfOfGroup.onBehalfOf').value == params.onBehalfOf }"
            class="radioBtn"
            id="radio-{{ i }}"
            type="radio"
            [value]="radio.value"
            name="onBehalfOf"
            formControlName="onBehalfOf"
            (change)="onBehalfOfChangeEvent(radio)"
          />
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**.spec file**

```
  it('should trigger onBehalfOfChangeEvent method on change', () => {
        const testee = component;
        expect(testee).toBeTruthy();
        let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.radioBtn'));
        spyOn(testee, 'onBehalfOfChangeEvent');
        de.triggerEventHandler('change', {});

        const x = { value: 'Self' };
        const value = x.value;
        component.onBehalfOfChangeEvent(value);
        expect(testee.onBehalfOfChangeEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(component.params.onBehalfOf).toEqual(value);
    });
```

Can anybody see why those two lines are not covered? Here is a stackBlitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-queryparam-gbb23f?file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts

Comment: Seems like you just overwrite `onBehalfOfChangeEvent` but never actually call its implementation. Try to add `and.callThrough()` to your spy on `onBehalfOfChangeEvent`. Does the test even pass where you check that `params.onBehalfOf` was correctly set?

Comment: When I add the .and.callThrough() the test fails on "Expected undefined to equal 'Self'."

Comment: Yes, that is because you need to call `de.triggerEventHandler('change', x)` in your test now.

Comment: It covered those lines, thanks. Do you want to add an official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way how you arrange the spies causes the test to be wrong. You are not calling the actual implementation of `onBehalfOfChangeEvent` but instead overwrite it (with your spy) and have it perform no operation when called.

This happens due to this line:

```
spyOn(testee, 'onBehalfOfChangeEvent');
```

Instead you want to edit it to specify a spy, as well as call the original method:

```
spyOn(testee, 'onBehalfOfChangeEvent').and.callThrough();
```

Now just change the way how you call your event handler from

```
de.triggerEventHandler('change', {});
```

to

```
de.triggerEventHandler('change', x);
```

and you are good to go.

You will also need to declare and initialize the variable `x` before you can use it. Be aware of this pitfall.